# g++ openCV compile error on line that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile and run the following program with `gcc test.cpp -o test`. But I'm getting this error:

```
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.hpp:49:10: error: 'cvaux.h' file not found with <angled>
      include; use "quotes" instead
#include <cvaux.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

That line isn't in the program though. What can I do to rectify this?

Program:

```
// Example showing how to read and write images
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cvaux.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage * pInpImg = 0;

    // Load an image from file - change this based on your image name
    pInpImg = cvLoadImage("my_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if(!pInpImg)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to load input image\n");
        return -1;
        }

    // Write the image to a file with a different name,
    // using a different image format -- .png instead of .jpg
    if( !cvSaveImage("my_image_copy.png", pInpImg) )
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to write image file\n");
        }

    // Remember to free image memory after using it!
    cvReleaseImage(&pInpImg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please avoid *any* code, that has IplImages in it or is using the opencv/*** c-api headers. it's all deprecated, they moved to c++ in 2010 already.

Comment: This code is a strange mix. Aren't all `.hpp`s and `cv2` things C++ anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"What can I do to rectify this?"

use the c++ api instead:

```
// Example showing how to read and write images
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    // Load an image from file - change this based on your image name
    Mat img = imread("my_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    if(img.empty())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to load input image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // this is just to show, that you won't have to pre-alloc
    // result-images with c++ any more..
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Write the image to a file with a different name,
    // using a different image format -- .png instead of .jpg
    if( ! imwrite("my_image_gray.png", gray) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to write image file\n");
    }

    // no need to release anything with c++ !   
    return 0;
}
```